# How is it valid to go from $\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|<C$ to $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq C|y-x|$?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta, lipschitz-functions

Let $A$ be the set of all functions $f$ such that, for some constant $C$, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|$ for all $y$ in an interval around $x$ (in other words $f$ is Lipschitz of order 1 at $x$).

Question 11-34 (c) from Spivak's Calculus goes somewhat like this

> Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then $f\in A$.

Answer book says

> If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then $\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists\delta$ such that
>   $$|y-x|<\delta\Rightarrow\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}-f'(x)\right|<\varepsilon$$
>   which means that, for $C=\varepsilon+|f'(x)|$,
>   $$\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|}<C$$
>   $$|f(y)-f(x)|\leq C|y-x|$$
>   $\square$.

This last step seems kinda shady. Since $x\neq y$ (because we have divided by it), how does one prove equality?

Comment: If $P$ is true then $P\lor Q$ is true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction

Comment: I See what you mean. So if $1<2$ is true  then $1\leq 2$ is also true. Since $A$ represents the cases where inequality or equality holds, if $f$ is a function where inequality holds, then obviously  $f\in A$ Thanks.

Comment: Note that the constant should be $C=\varepsilon+|f'(x)|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that $\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}<C$ for all $x\not=y$.

So $|f(x)-f(y)|<C|x-y|$ for all $x\not=y$.

For $x=y$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$ so $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: +1. I think it's important to note that $|f(x)-f(y)|=0=|x-y|$ in the $x=y$ case. If we just have $|s|=|t|$ this doesn't imply $|s|\leq C|t|$ (e.g. if $C<1$).

Comment: Thanks. It should also be noted that if $1<2$ is true then $1\leq 2$ is also true. Since $A$ represents the cases where inequality or equality holds, if $f$ is a function where inequality holds, then obviously $f∈A$. And also $\lim_{y\to x}|f(y)-f(x)|=\lim_{y\to x}|y-x|=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac {|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|}<C$$ which gives(since you know $y \ne x$) $$|f(y)-f(x)|<C|y-x|$$ "<" is a stronger condition than $"\le"$, so $$|f(y)-f(x)|\le C|y-x|$$

Answer (score 1):

First, if $x\neq y$ then $$\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|< C \implies \frac{\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|}{\left|y-x\right|}< C \implies \left|f(y)-f(x)\right|<C\left|y-x\right|$$

Next, if $x=y$ then take the limit as $y$ approaches $x$

$$\lim_{y\to x}\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|= \lim_{y\to x}|y-x|=0$$

therefore
$$\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|\le C\left|y-x\right|$$
for every $x,y$.